# Problem with addEventListener("load") when used with <iframe> in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, ecmascript-6

I have an `iframe` that is a target for a `form`. The `iframe` should remove the `main` element when `submit` is pressed. This works as expected in all major browsers except Firefox, where `main` is removed immediately on page load.

Is this just a bug in Firefox, or am I missing something?

---

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
  
  // Create an iframe and submit a form to it
  // ========================================

  const form = document.forms[0]
  form.setAttribute("target", "Response")

  const iframe = Object.assign(document.createElement("iframe"), {
    name: "Response"
  })
  iframe.hidden = true
  document.body.appendChild(iframe)

  iframe.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const main = document.querySelector("body > main")

    main.remove()

    iframe.hidden = false
  })
})
```

```html
<main>
  <form action=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzz-KveHder1A3CX8GcqZI6GR2MQj66PDRWNKoatIET_LXNqQs/exec method=get>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Foobar</legend>
      <label><input type=radio name=Foobar value=Foo>Foo</label><br>
      <label><input type=radio name=Foobar value=Bar>Bar</label><hr>
      <input type=submit value=Submit>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: *"The iframe should replace the main element..."* I don't see *replacement*. I see removal...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You’re right! I used bad terminology.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I set the `target` attribute via JavaScript.

Comment: Oh for...indeed, it's **right there, in the code**. Sorry. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Firefox is triggering `load` when the blank iframe loads and the others aren't.

A couple of approaches come to mind for addressing that:

- You could check the `location` of the `iframe` to make sure it's what you're expecting
- You could set the `load` handler only after you see a `submit` event on the form. The `submit` event will definitely be before the `load` related to it, because `submit` happens before form submission.

To me, the second way seems like the way to go.

---

Re using `location`, in rough terms (see comments):

```
iframe.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // *** Only process the event if the iframe's location is the expected origin
  if (String(iframe.contentWindow.location).startsWith("https://script.google.com")) {
    const main = document.querySelector("body > main")

    main.remove()

    iframe.hidden = false
  }
})
```

(`startsWith` is a bit newish, but easily polyfilled if necessary.)

Comment: I can’t use the `submit` event because of some security policy in Google Apps Script. I tried. So it must be submitted using plain HTML. Could you expand a bit more on your `location` suggestion?

Comment: @Tzar - It's fine if the form is submitted without using JavaScript, but having a submit handler just to know it was submitted shouldn't be a problem...? I'm adding more detail about `location` now, though.

Comment: @Tzar - Done. :-)